# Couchbase 401 Unauthorized

Tags: ruby, couchbase

I have a production cluster running Couchbase Community Edition, and it's been running fine for over 3 years now. Today, it started to give out:

```
[appserver1 root]$ bundle exec ruby cbtest.rb 

/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/couchbase-1.3.15/lib/couchbase/bucket.rb:146:in `continue': failed to execute HTTP request, Success (Not an error) (key="/pools/default/buckets/markets/ddocs", status="401" (Unauthorized), error=0x00) (Couchbase::Error::HTTP)
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/couchbase-1.3.15/lib/couchbase/bucket.rb:146:in `design_docs'
    from cbtest.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

Whereas, on another identical server

```
[appserver2 root]$ bundle exec ruby cbtest.rb 

[appserver2 root]$
```

Here this the code of the script:

```
require 'couchbase'

@client = Couchbase.new(:node_list => ['172.19.4.22'], :bucket => 'markets')

@client.design_docs
```

I decided to strace the process, and the only difference i could find was `Authorization: Basic 0g--` was present in the failing transaction, but absent in the succeeding one.

This is beyond me, as it's delving into the couchbase code.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, you should now explicitly pass user credentials. It is also done in preparations to Couchbase Server 5, where authentication and security in general has been improved a lot.

```
require 'couchbase'
@client = Couchbase.new(:node_list => ['172.19.4.22'], :bucket => 'markets',
                        :username => 'markets')
@client.design_docs
```

Comment: I am getting inconsistent results when passing credentials.  `@client.design_docs` works fine, but `set` doesn't.  If I don't pass credentials, `design_docs` doesn't work, but `set` works.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out libcouchbase2-core-2.7.4 made some changes to the authorization mechanism that didn't work with my current version of the rubygem 'couchbase'.

Rolling back to 2.7.3 fixed this.

See the changelog here

https://github.com/couchbase/libcouchbase/blob/master/RELEASE_NOTES.markdown

Comment: Looks like the CB team has abandoned Ruby completely. You can still get the previous versions here: https://developer.couchbase.com/server/other-products/release-notes-archives/c-sdk